# Flex3 and rollover effect

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am trying to get a zoom effect for items contained inside a tileList.

I have found exactly what I need:

**http://blog.flexwiz.net/sources/listdemo/bin/ListDemo.swf**

trouble is : that's for flex4 and **I use flex3** : can someone help me ?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Please visit following Link

```
http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/flex/tourdeflex/web/
```

in that please go Flex3/flex core components/Effect/zoom

you just need to do one thing that on MouseOver event of List zoom in or zoom out that List Item so that you can get what u want.. just try it once i have made that from this site. and unfortunately I have removed that code from my project so i can't give that to you... Sorry For that.. just try it once....